# IE8 Lockdown script behaviour

Tags: internet-explorer, batch-file, vbscript, internet-explorer-8

I have tried to get my head around this, Googled it and i am still at odds as to why this is happening (maybe im being thick?).

I have a VBScript called 'lockdownie' that opens Internet Explorer in a lockdown state (e.g. no address bar, no status bar, no tool bar and no menu bar) and I run this VBScript from a batch file.

The weird thing that happens is this. If i have the script navigate to a site with a www. prefix then it works like a charm. But if i have the script navigate to a site using the direct domain name (eg. "http: //domainname/sitename/...") then it appears the script is totally ignored and your standard, fully featured IE opens.

What am i doing wrong here? Am i just being thick??

My code for the vb script is...

```
Set oIE1 = WScript.CreateObject ("InternetExplorer.Application")

oIE1.Navigate "http://domainname/sitesname/...."
oIE1.Visible = 1
oIE1.AddressBar = 0
oIE1.StatusBar = 0
oIE1.ToolBar = 0
oIE1.MenuBar = 0
```

And just because, this is my batch file..

```
@echo off
pushd %~dp0
cscript lockdownie.vbs
```

Oh and before anyone says, i cant have kiosk mode as i need to close button.

Thanks for helping a person rapidly losing his hair.

Regards

Roy

Comment: Hi David and thanks for your reply. The code works as long as i navigate to a standard www. URL. Once i try to navigate to my domain site (WITHOUT the www. prefix) then it wont work.

Comment: Please provide an example to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Ah, thanks David. Maybe its something to do with the IIS server settings then? I will investigate. Thanks again :)

Comment: Right cant seem to find anything in the configuration of IIS. But i also think i may have not explained myself properly. Going to microsoft.com or www.microsoft.com works because its following a web URL DNS name. The problem seems to be if im accessing a site without using a DNS alias. Example if i have ServerA and lets say my web app is on port 9000 in IIS and i go http://ServerA:9000 thats when the VBScript doesnt work. Its bugging me because im sure im missing something obvious !!